# Update imported feeds to only get one taxonomy term per node

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes, hooks, feeds

I have used feeds to import some nodes with taxonomy term reference.

The source XML is the following one.

```
<items>
  <item>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <body>Test body 1</body>
    <term>My_term_foo</term>
    </item>
</items>
```

First import is OK. I edited `<term>My_term_bar</term>`, and started importing a second feed.
After the second time, the node has both "My_term_foo" and "My_term_bar," but I need only "My_term_bar" from the second import.

Is there any `hook_feeds_node_item_presave()` I can use to alter the values being imported?

EDIT:

My final code of hook_nodeapi inpired by [sel_space](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/28333/6324):

```
switch ($op) {
      case 'presave':
        if ($old_node = node_load($node->nid)) {
          $taxonomy = array_diff_assoc((array) $node->taxonomy, (array) $old_node->taxonomy);
          if (!empty($taxonomy)) {
            $node->taxonomy = $taxonomy;
          }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data needs to be modified before it is saved use this module : [Feeds tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper)

For advanced modification use hook_nodeapi in drupal 6 with the insert parameter , with hook_nodeapi load the old node like this :

```
$old_node = node_load(node->nid);
$node->taxonomy = array_diff($old_node->taxonomy,$node->taxonomy)
```

So now you are sure that the $node contain only the new value , Hope this  will help

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know feeds tamper, but it only change source. And if I try use hook_nodeapi then in node->taxonomy are both terms My_term_foo and My_term_bar and I dont know which is from second import.